# Got bitcoin on generated address, now my wallet doesn't have the address anymore

Tags: blockchain

I downloaded bitcoin.com wallet and immediately sent myself an email of my BTC address. Right after that I purchased some bitcoin through simplex. So the transactions (I made two, on the same address) went through, i can also see it on blockchain.info. The thing is, that I can't see it in my wallet. Also, the address I sent myself is also not visible in the wallet. I still have the email tho. I went back and forth with bitcoin support (one guy named Steven), i cleared my chache, generated all the new addresses, scanned for funds, I tryed everything he said. He also said that [image] the error message should not be showing, also stopped believing me about my issue. Ok, so here's the thing I want to know. How can I try to access my bitcoin just through the BTC address? Or at least, can I find out to wich wallet this address is linked to? Because if it is not linked to my wallet, which wallet is it linked then? Can a bitcoin address not be linked to a wallet?  If so, can anyone retrieve the money then? I will be very thankful for any response that could be helpful. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

> How can I try to access my bitcoin just through the BTC address?

You cannot, you need the private key that controls the address to access any bitcoin stored on it. (Wallet software will control the private key)

> Or at least, can I find out to wich wallet this address is linked to?

Without any other info, there is no way to tell which wallet an address is linked to.

> Because if it is not linked to my wallet, which wallet is it linked then? Can a bitcoin address not be linked to a wallet?

It is possible to generate an address that is controlled by a private key no one know. For example [see the 1BitcoinEater address](https://blockchain.info/address/1BitcoinEaterAddressDontSendf59kuE).

> If so, can anyone retrieve the money then? I will be very thankful for any response that could be helpful. Thank you in advance

Unfortunately, no. If your wallet does not contain the private key for that address, the money is likely gone forever.

It is very strange that the wallet would display an address that it does not have the private key for, for any further help you'll likely need to continue with the bitcoin.com customer service reps. Sorry for your loss :(